# Proof that $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \ge 0 \ \forall \ x, y \Rightarrow f$ is convex

Tags: convex-optimization

Proof that $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \ge 0 \ \forall \ x, y \Rightarrow f$ is convex.
I've differentiated both 2 sides and got this:
$\nabla^2 f(x)^T(x-y) + \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \succeq 0$
Then I choose $y = 0$:
$\nabla^2 f(x)^Tx + \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(0) \succeq 0$
But now I have no idea to continue.
Can anyone help me in this problem ?

Comment: You probably want to differentiate a function of $t$ related to convexity...

Comment: @Pedro What do you mean "a function of t" ? I attempt to proof the problem at the title but i don't know if it's true or false

Comment: Compute the derivative of $g(t) = f(\vec{x}t + \vec{y}(1-t))$ with respect to $t$. Might give you an idea of how to proceed.